# Using List Stream filter vs for loop

Tags: java, list, java-stream

In java 8 you can now use filter on a list to get another list based on the `Predicate` you supply.

so lets say I have normal for loop logic like this

```
for(Person p : personList){
    if(p.getName().Equals("John")){
         //do something with this person
    }
}
```

now using a filter like this

```
List<Person> johnList = personList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getName().Equals("John"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 

for(Person john : johnList){
    //do something with this person
}
```

it seems like using a filter would cause more overhead than using just a regular for loop because its not only looping through the entire list the first time but then you have to loop through the filtered list and do what you want with that filtered list.

Am I incorrect in how this works?

Comment: When in doubt, benchmark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing it the way you're doing it would indeed not be a good idea. But that's not how you're supposed to do it. The proper way would be

```
personList.stream()
          .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("John"))
          .forEach(p -> doSomethingWithPerson(p));
```

which does a single pass on the list and does not create any additional list.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because you only do half the job. Translating the first loop into Java 8, the result is

```
personList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getName().Equals("John"))
    .forEach(person -> // ...);
```

without the need of "collecting" the filtered elements.